# How to fix halfly done installation process in Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi2, recover

I tried to install Stellarium by following http://projectable.me/3d-printed-raspberry-pi-powered-planetarium-projector-nightlight-part-1/ tutorial. When I run the code

```
bzr co lp:stellarium stellarium
```

my internet connection was disconnected after few hours and the procedure was failed. It is difficult to run that code again because it takes more than five hours and 4Gb data. How I fix this? Thank you.